# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError After starting tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, java-native-interface

I am trying to call native method written in c++ on unix machine through Java.
I have declared static block as,

```
static {

    System.loadLibrary("loadData_v2");      
}
```

//C++ native library

```
private native String loadData( String args );
```

After starting tomcat my start up servlet gives

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.abc.loadData(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;
```

If I run standalone program to call native function then it works fine. But if I added same code in start up servlet it throws above exception.

If I print `System.getProperties().getProperty("java.library.path");`
it prints the correct path as `/home/mymechine/Desktop/SharedFile` where my .so file is located.

Can anybody guide me through this if I missed anything in tomcat configurations or I need to add ?

Comment: Is Tomcat running in your home machine?

Comment: yes tomcat is running it starts with printing logs from web application

Comment: @Sarang.C Did u find the solution? I am also facing the same problem now.